# Restrict push to certain remotes for a branch

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

I have two remotes, one for production and one for GitHub. As I have to push certain files to the productions that must not land on GitHub I would like to restrict a branch to avoid accidents.

Is there a way to tell my git client that it should **never** push the branch "deploy" to remote "github" and only push this branch to "production"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[kowsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152729/1256452) is the right one, provided your Git is at least 1.8.2 (and if not you should upgrade :-) ).  However, the linked examples are faulty.

The [pre-push hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) is invoked with two arguments, which provide:

- the name of the remote, if a named remote is used, else the URL
- the URL (the result of expanding the named remote, if a named remote is used)

What is *to be pushed*, which is something you specify at the time you run `git push`, is provided to the hook *on its standard input*.  This is where the two linked examples are both broken.

If you run:

```
git push github refspec1 refspec2 ... refspecN
```

then the reference(s) being pushed are those given on this command line.

If you run:

```
git push github
```

(with no refspecs), the set of branches to be pushed is... well, it's complicated, but in *modern* Git, it defaults to the current branch.

The sample pre-push hooks *assume* that *only* the current branch is to be pushed.  Since that's the modern default, the samples will probably work, up until you accidentally run:

```
git push github deploy
```

(while on, say, `master`), and then they won't, and you may be sad. :-)

To fix them, use a githook that reads, e.g.:

```
#! /bin/sh
[ "$1" = github ] || exit 0 # allow if not pushing to github
while read lref lhash rref rhash; do
    case "$lref" in
    refs/heads/deploy)
        echo "error: attempt to push 'deploy' branch to github" 1>&2
        exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

This will allow:

```
git push github master:deploy
```

(which creates or updates a `deploy` on remote `github`, but using *local* branch `master`, not *local* branch `deploy`) while forbidding:

```
git push github deploy:oops
```

(which pushes the *local* `deploy` to a branch named `oops`).

Should you wish to have more complicated rules, write them up.  Note that if you want to prevent the use of `git push https://github.com/...` to bypass your own hook, you can check `$2` as well as `$1`.  Of course, if you are that determined to bypass your own hook, you could easily run `git push --no-verify` to disable your hook.

Answer (score 4):

[Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) are what you're looking for. You can set up a server side pre-receive hook, that works for everyone trying to push to your repo, that accepts or rejects pushes depending on the current branch, or a similar local pre-push hook. Examples for the latter can be found [here](https://dev.ghost.org/prevent-master-push/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/pixelhandler/5718585).